# Edit update attributes in a before_update callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, callback

I am saving a rather complex form with some nested polymorphic forms. I want to be able to intercept the datetime fields that are in the nested forms and set them to UTC.

Is there a way in the before_update callback on the model to modify the attributes sent to the update_attributes method?

Answer (score 0):

you can used someting like following

```
def before_update
  self.some_date = change_to_utc(self.some_date)
end
```

Comment: so in the before_update callback, attributes on self are set to the new unsaved data coming in, not the old saved data?